# localstorage not getting saved to

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a simple text editor and when I try and save to localstorage it works if I refresh the page but if I clear the text then refresh and click load from storage it won't work.
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Text Editor</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #000;
    }

    div {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #000;
    }

    h1 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    textarea {
      width: 80%;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #000;
    }

    button {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #downloadBtn,
    #clearStorageBtn,
    #loadStorageBtn,
    #toggleThemeBtn,
    #printBtn,
    #fullscreenBtn {
      background: #4CAF50;
      color: #fff;
    }

    #discardBtn,
    #clearTextBtn {
      background: #f44336;
      color: #fff;
    }

    #footer {
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 20px 0;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #emailLink {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Text Editor</h1>
    <textarea id="editor" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="downloadBtn" onclick="downloadText()">Download</button>
    <button id="discardBtn" onclick="discardText()">Discard</button>
    <button id="clearTextBtn" onclick="clearText()">Clear Text</button>
    <button id="saveBtn" onclick="saveTextManually()">Save</button>
    <button id="clearStorageBtn" onclick="clearLocalStorage()">Clear Storage</button>
    <button id="loadStorageBtn" onclick="loadFromLocalStorage()">Load from Storage</button>
    <button id="toggleThemeBtn" onclick="toggleTheme()">Toggle Theme</button>
    <button id="printBtn" onclick="printText()">Print</button>
    <button id="fullscreenBtn" onclick="toggleFullscreen()">Fullscreen</button>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <a id="emailLink" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=email@email.com target="_blank">Contact
      us</a>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      // Load text from local storage on page load
      loadFromLocalStorage();
  
      // Add event listener for input changes
      document.querySelector('#editor').addEventListener('input', handleInput);
  
      // Add event listener for the "Save" button
      document.querySelector('#saveBtn').addEventListener('click', saveTextManually);
  
      // Add event listener for the "Load from Storage" button
      document.querySelector('#loadStorageBtn').addEventListener('click', loadFromLocalStorage);
    });
  
    function handleInput() {
      // Save text to local storage when input changes
      saveToLocalStorage(document.querySelector('#editor').value);
    }
  
    function downloadText() {
      const text = document.querySelector('#editor').value;
      const blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = 'text_file.txt';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  
    function discardText() {
      document.querySelector('#editor').value = '';
      // Clear local storage when text is discarded
      clearLocalStorage();
    }
  
    function clearText() {
      document.querySelector('#editor').value = '';
      // Save text to local storage when text is cleared
      saveToLocalStorage('');
    }
  
    function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  const storedText = localStorage.getItem('textEditorContent');
  document.querySelector('#editor').value = storedText !== null ? storedText : '';
}


  
    function saveTextManually() {
      // Save text to local storage when "Save" button is clicked
      saveToLocalStorage(document.querySelector('#editor').value);
    }
  
    function clearLocalStorage() {
      localStorage.removeItem('textEditorContent');
    }
  
    function saveToLocalStorage(text) {
      localStorage.setItem('textEditorContent', text || '');
    }
  </script>
  
  
  
  
  
  
</body>

</html>
```

I tried lots of stuff like asking chatGPT but that didn't work either. ChatGPT tried a lot of different approaches none worked. There are no errors in the console of Inspect Element.

Currently when I type something into the text field and refresh the page it stays there but if I clear the text and then click load from storage nothing happens. I thought it was because the autosave saved the text as null or an empty string but after adding an if loop to prevent that nothing happens.

My expected result is that when i clear the text field then refresh the page and then click load from storage it should load the text that i typed before refreshing and clearing it. For example if i type 'hello' then click save and then clear the text field and refresh the page it should show 'hello' in the text field after clicking load from storage.

Comment: probably best to also give info the steps that you are doing, what's the expected outcome, what's the current (not working) outcome..

Comment: Start by putting your script in its own file, and loading that with `<script src="yourfile.js" async defer></script>` in the `<head>`, so that it loads in parallel with the rest of the page, but only _runs_ once the page is ready. Don't inline scripts in your page, you're just going to miss out on all the help your code editor can give you if you load a pure JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving to local storage whenever they hit save *and also* whenever the text is updated.

```js
    // Add event listener for input changes
    document.querySelector('#editor').addEventListener('input', handleInput);
    // Add event listener for the "Save" button
    document.querySelector('#saveBtn').addEventListener('click', saveTextManually);

 
    function handleInput() {
      // Save text to local storage when input changes
      saveToLocalStorage(document.querySelector('#editor').value);
    }

    function saveTextManually() {
      // Save text to local storage when "Save" button is clicked
      saveToLocalStorage(document.querySelector('#editor').value);
    }
```

Remove the `handleInput` listener.

You have a "Clear Text" and a "Clear Storage" button but you are also clearing storage when you click "Clear Text" and that looks like a mistake too.

```js
    function discardText() {
      document.querySelector('#editor').value = '';
      // Clear local storage when text is discarded
      clearLocalStorage();
    }
  
    function clearText() {
      document.querySelector('#editor').value = '';
      // Save text to local storage when text is cleared
      saveToLocalStorage('');
    }
```

A call to `saveToLocalStorage('')` is the same as a call to  `clearLocalStorage()`. So remove that from the `clearText` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like an input event is being executed upon your `textarea` after the storage was cleared, prompting a save of its current content, which was not cleared. Therefore, it seems to me that you should also clear your `textarea` when your storage is cleared:

```
    function clearLocalStorage() {
      clearText();
      localStorage.removeItem('textEditorContent');
    }
```